# How does ECU know the hand brake is on?

Tags: electronic-control-module, handbrake, alfa-romeo, giulietta

I was reviewing the data around the DTC event, and it said the hand brake was on. I  assumed it was a software bug, because I was sure the hand brake was off, but today after jacking up the rear I noticed that there is ever so slight drag on the brake pads with the hand brake off. The wheel is spinning but there is a sound of slight friction on the brake pads. So how does ECU tell if the hand brake is on or off? The car is Alfa Romeo Giulietta 2011.

Comment: Most cars have a switch located at the handbrake mechanism. When the handbrake is applied, the switch closes and tells the car it's engaged. I'm not sure about your Alfa, though. It could do something totally different. As for the drag, this is not uncommon. Brakes usually self adjust, which puts them out right at the point where they might make a little bit of noise.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I think the there is a software bug re that DTC event context. I compared the front and rear wheels. Rear ones have significantly more friction sound. I'll post a separate question with the video about the sound.

Answer (score 1):

> **So how does ECU tell if the hand brake is on or off? The car is Alfa Romeo Giulietta 2011.**

There's a switch under the centre console at the front of the handbrake lever.

You can see this in videos such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XRenXH6p4M) (no affiliation, I found the video when looking for info about the cigarette lighter)

[image: handbrake switch position]